# Mongo query count n+1 scenario

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given a mongo collection with properties "createdDate", "eventType"  and few other, I want to query for documents between a give date range and list the count by eventType.
As of now I have a lengthy approach:

- Query for distinct `eventType` between given date range

```
db.EventMessage.distinct( "eventType" , { "env" : "prod" });
```

Lets say this query yeilds, Foo1EventType,Foo2EventType, Foo3EventType etc.

- For each of the eventType from the above, query document count for given date range

```
db.EventMessage.count ( { "eventType" : "Foo1EventType" ,  "createdDate" :  {"$gte": new Date("2015-05-22") , "$lt" : new Date("2015-05-23") }  });
```

Above query gives me the count of events for Foo1EventType between the dates range specified. However I need to run this query for each eventType separately. I want to check for better performing query which iterates over all distinct eventTypes and lists the count against the eventType.
MongoDB contains more than 50K documents/day and total 6 months data is maintained at any point in time.

Is there a better performing query to yield the count by each eventType for given range of dates?

Comment: can you post sample documents with expected output?

Comment: @yogesh I added few sample queries. Sample documents contains unrelated fields. For this question. I am concerned with the 2 properties mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you are aggregating time-based data and want to have fast reports for counts over time, a common approach to consider is [pre-aggregated reports](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/). An alternative to the separate distinct & count queries you have suggested would be to do a single query with the MongoDB [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), but pre-aggregation is more efficient than a full recalc (especially if there is historical data that does not change).

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement for large data set you should first [index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/) your documents or use [shard index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key-indexes/).

To find out all distinct `eventType` and then used [forEach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) for all distinct data as below :

```
db.EventMessage.distinct("eventType", {
  "env": "prod"
}).forEach(function(data) {
  var doc = db.EventMessage.find({
    "eventType": data,
    "createdDate": {
      "$gte": new Date("2015-05-22"),
      "$lt": new Date("2015-05-23")
    }
  }).count();
  print(doc);
})
```